# Can we train custom NER model using spacy's larger model on smaller text and do inferencing on larger text?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, spacy-3

I have this confusion, as I wanted to extract street addresses from text, so I am planning to train a custom NER model using Spacy's larger model. I have to do inferencing on larger text like text from a multi-page pdf, so should I train the model on text of that scale, i.e., text from multi-page pdfs or training the model on smaller text like small paragraphs will also give us good results on text of that scale? What do you guys suggest?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about DL theory and/or methodology - please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deep-learning/info

Answer (score 1):

For the spaCy model architectures there's no benefit to using text longer than a paragraph or so. Additionally you'll run into issues with memory more easily if you try to do so. You should preprocess your text into paragraph-sized chunks. (If your use case requires longer documents, that's fine, you just wrap the process of splitting them up and merging them back together.)

For an NER task in general there's no benefit to using really long texts either. Think about it - if you have a paragraph and can pick out the names of people and places, does having a whole 20 page document including that actually help?

Another thing is that you say you're going to use spaCy's larger model, but note retraining the pretrained pipelines is generally not recommended, you'll run into catastrophic forgetting and it doesn't help that much. It's usually fine to just reuse the word vectors. If you use Transformers that will also automatically use a fine-tuning approach and you don't have to use the spaCy pipeline as a starting point. You can read more about catastrophic forgetting in [the FAQ](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8226#:%7E:text=My%20retrained%20model%20forgot%20pretrained%20entities).